Issue with the roots of the Equation of Time
Regarding the famous derivation of the Equation of Time available here  that i'm trying to rewrite a modern version with much more detailed steps:
http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/mul/mueller.pdf
at page 5, relation 11:
$$a_n=\frac{i}{\pi} \oint \frac{\cos \alpha\left(z^{n / 2}+z^{-n / 2}\right)}{\sin ^2 \alpha\left(z^2-2 \frac{\left(1+\cos ^2 \alpha\right)}{\sin ^2 \alpha} z+1\right)} \mathrm{d} z$$
The author states that denominator has the roots:
$$N_1=\left(\frac{1-\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}\right)^2=\tan ^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}, \quad N_2=\left(\frac{1+\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}\right)^2=\cot ^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}$$
However.... if i solve the polynomial at the denominator, i get the following two roots:
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{4-2 \sin (\alpha)^2 \pm 4 \sqrt{1-\sin (\alpha)^2}}{\sin (\alpha)^2}$$
where obviously if we simplify we get for example for one of the roots:
$$\dfrac{1+\cos^2(\alpha)+2|\cos(\alpha)|}{\sin^2(\alpha)}$$
We can't simplify it further as it's done in the paper because of the absolute value (and even a plot seems to show that the simplification can't be done!).
Did i miss something or did the author made an error?

Yes, you missed something.
For all $\alpha\in\mathbb R,\ \cos\alpha$ is either negative or non-negative. If it is negative, $|\cos\alpha|=-\cos\alpha$ and so
$$\frac{1+\cos^2\alpha+2|\cos\alpha|}{\sin^2\alpha}=\frac{1+\cos^2\alpha-2\cos\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}=\left(\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)^2=\tan^2\frac\alpha2$$
If, instead, it is non-negative, then $|\cos\alpha|=\cos\alpha$ and so
$$\frac{1+\cos^2\alpha+2|\cos\alpha|}{\sin^2\alpha}=\frac{1+\cos^2\alpha+2\cos\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha}=\left(\frac{1+\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}\right)^2=\cot^2\frac\alpha2$$

This is one of the two roots. The other root is going to just be the other case. There is thus never a difference; you will always get both $\tan^2\frac\alpha2$ and $\cot^2\frac\alpha2$ as the two roots, for all possible $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. It is just a matter of which one you pick first.

Oh yes i forgot that point. Thanks a lot for your help!
